# How to optimize working (but slow) stair permutation function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

The problem is, given a number of blocks, how many ways are there to build stairs using that finite amount of blocks where there is always any incline between any two neighboring steps.

This means that a two step staircase from 100 to 1 step is valid. Of course, more blocks mean you can have more steps.

I wrote a function that accomplishes this, albeit very slowly when it gets to larger number of blocks, and I'm not sure how I can improve its runtime.

If you want a quick breakdown of my logic, it works out logically that by recursively expanding the highest step into all possible permutations of two steps (that would still put the second step above the former second step), eventually you get all possible step permutations.

Maybe there's a more mathy way of doing this, but I approached it from a programming pov. Welcome to hear any different suggestions though, if my approach is just too slow!

```py
def solution(n):
    cases = 0
    q = [[x, n - x] for x in range(n) if x > n - x and n - x > 0]
    
    while q:
        curr = q.pop(0)
        cases += 1
        q += [[x, curr[0] - x, *curr[1:]] for x in range(curr[1], curr[0] - curr[1]) if x > curr[0] - x > curr[1]]
        
    return cases
```

output, to show it works

```py
>>> solution(15)
[8, 7]
[9, 6]
[10, 5]
[11, 4]
[12, 3]
[13, 2]
[14, 1]
[6, 5, 4]
[7, 5, 3]
[8, 4, 3]
[7, 6, 2]
[8, 5, 2]
[9, 4, 2]
[10, 3, 2]
[8, 6, 1]
[9, 5, 1]
[10, 4, 1]
[11, 3, 1]
[12, 2, 1]
[6, 4, 3, 2]
[6, 5, 3, 1]
[7, 4, 3, 1]
[7, 5, 2, 1]
[8, 4, 2, 1]
[9, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
26
```

Comment: if you only want number of cases instead of printing all cases, then we can do this O(n^2)

Comment: that would work @DushyantSingh

Comment: This is the "subset sum" problem where your set is `range(1, N)` and the sum is `N`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative recursive/backtracking approach:

```
def solve_recursive(n):
    solutions = []
    def f(sol, i, n):
        if n == 0 and len(sol) >= 2:
            solutions.append(sol)

        for j in range(i+1, n+1):
            sol.append(j)
            f(sol, j, n-j)
            sol.pop()
    f([], 0, n)
    return len(solutions)
```

It is a bit more efficient than your version, at n=105 this takes `3.3s` on my computer, compared to `13.4s` in the version you posted.

The idea is to recursively fill the buckets using higher and higher values, so that the requirement is met.

If we are only interested in the count, and not the paths, we can get faster by omitting the path bookkeeping:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def solution_faster(n):
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def f(i, cnt, n):
        if n == 0 and cnt >= 2:
            return 1
        ans = 0        
        for j in range(i+1, n+1):
            ans += f(j, cnt+1, n-j)
        return ans

    return f(0, 0, n)
```

This takes `0.04s` for n=105 on my computer. But we can do even better by removing the `cnt` as well!

```
def solution_even_faster(n):
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def f(i, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        ans = 0        
        for j in range(i+1, n+1):
            ans += f(j, n-j)
        return ans

    ans = 0
    for j in range(1, n//2 + 1):
        ans += f(j, n-j)
    return ans
```

Now we have `O(N^3)` (pseudo-polynomial) time complexity. This takes `0.008s` in my computer.

`O(N^2)` solutions are possible with dynamic programming approaches as well. I suggest checking out this reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-subsets-with-sum-equal-to-x/

Comment: i noticed you edited out the time complexity - is it worse than o(n^2)?

Comment: This seems O(2^N) which is incredibly worse than O(N^2). Your code for N=500 runs 180x slower than N=100 and not 25x as N^2 would be

Comment: can i ask why the n==0 base case returns 1? because a step height of 0 wouldn't be valid?

Comment: Sorry this is not O(N^2) you're (partially) right: it's O(N^3). We are doing N operations in every f() call, which I forgot to account for. @JBernardo

Comment: Because I didn't account for it @notacorn Feel free to polish the rough edges :)

Comment: Added a reference for O(N^2) solution @notacorn

Comment: @Cihan The subset sum problem is notorious for exponential complexity and even with the cache I don't think you will can accomplish in polynomial time

Comment: Yes it is a pseudo-polynomial solution. Note that N is both the sum and the size of the input array. So yes, definitely not a polynomial solution, I agree. @JBernardo

Comment: can you explain why `maxsize` is set to `None` in the `@lru_cache` annotation? (pros/cons)

Comment: like is there a way of actually determining a specific number for `maxsize` or usually setting it to `None` for best performance is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Let `dp[i][j]` denote number of ways you can get `j` blocks using the first `i` steps.

In 0th row, only `dp[0][0]` will be 1 and everything else will be 0 because initially with 0 steps you can get 0 block in one way.

For other rows, `dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] + dp[i - 1][j - i]` because `dp[i - 1][j]` was old number of ways to get `j` blocks and after using block of size `i` then `dp[i - 1][j - i]` will also contribute to `dp[i][j]`.

This uses `O(n ^ 2)` space complexity. But you can reduce it to `O(n)` by observing that current row depends on previous row only. So this reduces space to `O(n)`. But time complexity remains the same which is `O(n ^ 2)`.

```
def solution(n):
    # we can reach 0 in 1 way which using no blocks
    prev = [0 for _  in range(n + 1)]
    prev[0] = 1

    # start from n - 1 block and go up to 1
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        curr = list(prev)
        for j in range(i, n + 1):
            curr[j] = curr[j] + prev[j - i]
        prev = list(curr)
    return prev[-1]
```

Here `prev` denotes `dp[i-1]` and `curr` denotes `dp[i]`

Comment: Note: You can also go from 1 to n - 1. Order doesn't matter. :)

Comment: an explanation of how prev/curr is populated would be greatly appreciated

Comment: and like what each index sort of represents?

Comment: @notacorn added explanation